# Newey West Adjustment in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, portfolio

I have a following data.table

```
PrevMonth   Portfolio   ExcessReturn
196306  Portfolio 1 -0.3035362
196306  Portfolio 10    -1.250766
196306  Portfolio 2 1.08474287
196306  Portfolio 3 -0.628247
196306  Portfolio 4 -0.2490027
196306  Portfolio 5 0.47310531
196306  Portfolio 6 0.36409036
196306  Portfolio 7 -0.8392494
196306  Portfolio 8 -0.5734843
196306  Portfolio 9 -1.9914358
196306  Portfolio LS    -0.9472298
196307  Portfolio 1 3.29524841
196307  Portfolio 10    6.47879571
196307  Portfolio 2 2.8880775
196307  Portfolio 3 4.35083011
196307  Portfolio 4 4.2523679
196307  Portfolio 5 4.30965798
196307  Portfolio 6 4.68137361
196307  Portfolio 7 4.34311633
196307  Portfolio 8 7.04824776
196307  Portfolio 9 7.35395871
196307  Portfolio LS    3.18354731
196308  Portfolio 1 -0.4837659
196308  Portfolio 10    -0.8704307
196308  Portfolio 2 -1.8642527
```

What I want to be able to perform a t-test to reject the null that Monthly Average Excess Return is zero and to do so I want to make a Newey West Adjustment with a lag of 1 in errors. So I regress Excess Return on a constant grouped by Month and make Newey West adjustment.

I finally want to report the Newey West Adjusted t-statistic and monthly average excess return for each portfolio.

Here is what I have done:

```
TS_Sample_Beta_Portfolio_Final<-Sample_Beta_Portfolio_Final[,list(coeftest(lm(ExcessReturn~1),
                                  vcov = NeweyWest(lm(ExcessReturn~1),lag = 12))),by=c("PrevMonth")]
```

where Sample_Beta_Portfolio has the above data.

But this doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `list` call encapsulates the output of `coeftest` inside a list, that is, a list with one element of class `coeftest`. What you want, instead, is a list with each individual statistic produced by `coeftest`. So you can use `as.list` instead:

```r
Sample_Beta_Portfolio_Final[, as.list(coeftest(lm(ExcessReturn~1), 
                                               vcov=NeweyWest(lm(ExcessReturn~1), 
                                                              lag=12))),
                            by=c("PrevMonth")]
```

The problem with this approach is that it won't name your result properly, since `as.list` drops your `dimnames`. An alternative would be to write a `fit` function that renames the output list.

First, load the libraries and the data:

```
library(data.table)
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)

dat = fread("PrevMonth -Portfolio   ExcessReturn
196306-Portfolio 1 -0.3035362
196306-Portfolio 10    -1.250766
196306-Portfolio 2 1.08474287
196306-Portfolio 3 -0.628247
196306-Portfolio 4 -0.2490027
196306-Portfolio 5 0.47310531
196306-Portfolio 6 0.36409036
196306-Portfolio 7 -0.8392494
196306-Portfolio 8 -0.5734843
196306-Portfolio 9 -1.9914358
196306-Portfolio LS    -0.9472298
196307-Portfolio 1 3.29524841
196307-Portfolio 10    6.47879571
196307-Portfolio 2 2.8880775
196307-Portfolio 3 4.35083011
196307-Portfolio 4 4.2523679
196307-Portfolio 5 4.30965798
196307-Portfolio 6 4.68137361
196307-Portfolio 7 4.34311633
196307-Portfolio 8 7.04824776
196307-Portfolio 9 7.35395871
196307-Portfolio LS    3.18354731
196308-Portfolio 1 -0.4837659
196308-Portfolio 10    -0.8704307
196308-Portfolio 2 -1.8642527")
```

Then, defined the `fit` function and apply it to each group:

```
fit = function(x) {
  m = lm(ExcessReturn~1, x)
  v = NeweyWest(m, lag=12)
  ct = coeftest(m, vcov=v)
  out = as.list(ct)
  names(out) = dimnames(ct)[[2]]
  out[["r2"]] = summary(m)$r.squared
  out
}

dat[, fit(.SD), by="PrevMonth"]

#>           PrevMonth   Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|) r2
#> 1: 196306-Portfolio -0.4419102  0.1596251 -2.768425 1.984085e-02  0
#> 2: 196307-Portfolio  4.7441110  0.2203860 21.526374 1.044449e-09  0
#> 3: 196308-Portfolio -1.0728164  0.1614823 -6.643553 2.191480e-02  0
```

Note that this will produce warnings because you are specifying more lags than there are observations in each group.

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me how to get the R-squared from the regression as well?

Comment: Same thing as any other linear model: just add this to your `fit` list (in my example, it's called `out`): `summary(m)$r.squared`

Comment: I did the following, commented out the names row, since that probably won't work withR-squared.                                                                                                            
 fit = function(x) {
  m = lm(ExcessReturn~1, x)
  v = NeweyWest(m, lag=12)
  ct = coeftest(m, vcov=v)
  out = as.list(ct,summary(m)$r.squared)
  #names(out) = dimnames(ct)[[2]]
  out
}
Beta_Stat<- Sample_Beta_Portfolio_Final[, fit(.SD), by=c("Month")]                                It doesn't attached the R-squared to out.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. The `fit` function returns a list with each of your columns. You want to add a new column with R2, so all you need to do is add a new element to the list, with proper name. You would do this by assigning `out[["r2"]] <-` in the `fit` function. I modified the code above to show how. Note that your regression fits the data pretty badly, so the R2 is zero for every subgroup in these data.