# Newey West on multiple linear regression

Tags: r, data.table, portfolio

I have the  following Data Table:

```
 Month    P_name  ER       F1   F2     F3   F4    F5    F6   F7
196307   P1    3.2952484 -0.39 -0.56 -0.83 0.27 -0.47  0.66 -1.15
196307   P10    6.4787957 -0.39 -0.56 -0.83 0.27 -0.47  0.66 -1.15
196307   P2    2.8880775 -0.39 -0.56 -0.83 0.27 -0.47  0.66 -1.15
196307   P3    4.3508301 -0.39 -0.56 -0.83 0.27 -0.47  0.66 -1.15
196307   P4    4.2523679 -0.39 -0.56 -0.83 0.27 -0.47  0.66 -1.15
196307   P5    4.3096580 -0.39 -0.56 -0.83 0.27 -0.47  0.66 -1.15
196307   P6    4.6813736 -0.39 -0.56 -0.83 0.27 -0.47  0.66 -1.15
196307   P7    4.3431163 -0.39 -0.56 -0.83 0.27 -0.47  0.66 -1.15
196307   P8    7.0482478 -0.39 -0.56 -0.83 0.27 -0.47  0.66 -1.15
196307   P9    7.3539587 -0.39 -0.56 -0.83 0.27 -0.47  0.66 -1.15
196307   PLS    3.1835473 -0.39 -0.56 -0.83 0.27 -0.47  0.66 -1.15
196308   P1   -0.4837659  5.07 -0.94  1.67 0.25 -0.79  0.40 -0.40
196308   P10   -0.8704307  5.07 -0.94  1.67 0.25 -0.79  0.40 -0.40
196308   P2   -1.8642527  5.07 -0.94  1.67 0.25 -0.79  0.40 -0.40
196308   P3   -2.0056693  5.07 -0.94  1.67 0.25 -0.79  0.40 -0.40
196308   P4   -1.2075884  5.07 -0.94  1.67 0.25 -0.79  0.40 -0.40
196308   P5   -3.0759695  5.07 -0.94  1.67 0.25 -0.79  0.40 -0.40
196308   P6   -2.1879341  5.07 -0.94  1.67 0.25 -0.79  0.40 -0.40
196308   P7   -0.7625329  5.07 -0.94  1.67 0.25 -0.79  0.40 -0.40
196308   P8   -0.9208842  5.07 -0.94  1.67 0.25 -0.79  0.40 -0.40
196308   P9   -2.5052435  5.07 -0.94  1.67 0.25 -0.79  0.40 -0.40
196308   PLS   -0.3866648  5.07 -0.94  1.67 0.25 -0.79  0.40 -0.40
196309   P1   -0.1691145 -1.57 -0.30  0.18 0.27 -0.48 -0.76  0.24
196309   P10    7.7057777 -1.57 -0.30  0.18 0.27 -0.48 -0.76  0.24
196309   P2    0.4863887 -1.57 -0.30  0.18 0.27 -0.48 -0.76  0.24
196309   P3   -0.8416363 -1.57 -0.30  0.18 0.27 -0.48 -0.76  0.24
196309   P4   -0.4628775 -1.57 -0.30  0.18 0.27 -0.48 -0.76  0.24
```

What I want to do is regress ER ~ F1 + F2 + F3 + F4 + F5 + F6 + F7 and do Newey West Adjustments for standard errors with a lag of 1.

Finally I want to report the  coefficients of the the Fs, the intercept, t-stat, and adjusted R squared and number of observations used for each regression for each of the P_name.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please use `dput()` or something similar to share your table in a better way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Newey West Adjustment in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64473518/newey-west-adjustment-in-data-table)

Comment: Mostly yes. I am not sure how to get the value of the number of observations used. And also, I dont know how to extend the output to include headers for all columns, so I am not sure which column corresponds to which independent variable.

Comment: number of observations: `nobs(model)`. The columns are in the same order as the coefficients in `coef(model)`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first problem, you can run a linear regression model and get Newey-West standard errors like this:

```
library(xts) # for time series 
library(lmtest) # for coeftest; requires the sandwich package

# create sample data
set.seed(123)
timeindex <- seq.Date(from = as.Date('2000-01-01'),
                      to = as.Date('2002-09-26'),
                      by = 'days')
sample_data <- xts(matrix(rnorm(1000*8), ncol = 8),
                   order.by = timeindex)
names(sample_data) <- c('ER', 'F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4', 'F5', 'F6', 'F7')

# run the regression model
lm1 <- lm(ER ~ F1 + F2 + F3 + F4 + F5 + F6 + F7, 
          data = sample_data)

summary(lm1) # values without Newey-West
coeftest(lm1,vcov=NeweyWest(lm1,lag = 1, verbose=T)) # with Newey-West std. errors
```

To get the different values for each P_name you could either filter the data before feeding it to lm for each P_name manually, if you don't have too many of them. Alternatively, you could write a function to do it for you and run a simple loop over the P_name portfolios.